# Short form of the condition of the conditional-if in C

Tags: c

```
inline int is_empty(list head) {
    return !head ? 1: 0;
}
```

I can see that "is_empty" function return 1 if the the list given is empty, 0 if it's not, also this short form of conditional-if is understandable, but can anyone explain to me how the condition works here, I mean how does the symbol '!' works with a pointer empty and does the cond-if just accepts 1 as true or any value except NULL is enough for the condition to be verified.

Comment: `!head` evaluates to 0 if `head` is not a null pointer, and to 1 if it is a null pointer.  Yes; the condition part of the ternary operator looks for zero as false and non-zero as true.

Comment: Note that you don't really need the condition here… you could just `return !head;`.

Comment: There is no difference between `!head ? 1: 0` and `!head`. Your compiler knows that and will probably generate the same code for both, but the rest of us have to think about it because it might have been `!head ? 0: 1`. You could write the second one as `!!head` but my suggestion would be to go for clarity and write `return head != NULL` (or `head == NULL` as the case may be).

Comment: This *function* is nonsense:: `int is_zero(int val){ return val? 0 :1;}`

Comment: @wildplasser What's nonsens about that?

Comment: Because you **dont need** a function. `if(!val)` would do exactly the same as `if (some_useless_function(val))`

Comment: @wildplasser, it's not nonsense if the List implementation changes such that List is a valid object even when it is actually empty.

Comment: If the implementaton changes, you'l lhave to change this beast. One way or the other. The way it is presented here it is nonsense in its purest form: cargo cult.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first you have to understand that if pointer points to `NULL` it is pointing to special address `0`. So if `head` is `NULL`, `!head` would return 1.

Second, `x ? 5 : 10` is same as `x != 0 ? 5 : 10`, and `!x ? 5 : 10` would be the same as `x == 0 ? 5 : 10`. Putting first point into this analogy `!head ? 1 : 0` would be the same as `head == 0 ? 1 : 1` which is the same as you `head == NULL ? 1 : 0`

Third, this could be written simply as:

```
inline int is_empty(list head){
  return !head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code has two flaws:

First. the expression: rewrite the code to make it more readable:

```
inline int is_empty(list head){
    return head ? 0: 1;
}
```

Second. The name implies it returns a boolean value, 0 is false, and non-zero true. THis is how I would write it. Way more readable:

```
inline int is_empty(list head){
    return head==NULL;
}
```

Regarding an expression, the semantics of C are the following:

If the type of an expression expr is (sometype*) --a pointer-- then the result of the expression is false if expr == 0 (the null pointer).

so in this case:

```
a ? b : c
```

the result of this expression is b if a is true, c otherwise.

For your expression:

```
!head ? 1 : 0
```

the result would be 1 if (!head) is true. Let me rewrite it for simplification: ( a ? b : c) is equivalent to (!a ? c: b):

```
head ? 0 : 1
```

So the function will return 0 if head != 0 (NULL) and 1 otherwise.

Comment: I got your point here, thanks but I was focusing on learning, using the ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

In general, `!x` yields zero (meaning false) if x is non-zero and non-zero (meaning true) if x is zero. So the expression `!head` yields zero if `head` is non-zero (that is, not NULL, since this is a pointer) and non-zero if `head` is zero (that is, NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, with if in C, if the value is 0, the expression evaluates to false, anything else is true. Thus, if (NULL), the expression will evaluate to false. When you do this if (!NULL), the expression will evaluate to not false, which is true.

For this example, the output will be `(null)`:

```
ptr = NULL

if (ptr)
  printf("not null");
else:
  printf("null");
```